# Correlation matrix for biostatistics

Tags: biostatistics, correlation-matrix

I want to convert the expression of the genes from an array to a gene correlation matrix, to know the correlation of each gene with the other genes.
I have 6 samples, 3 controls and 3 test, is it correct to compute the correlation matrix using the 6 samples? Should I consider the 6 samples or just one control and one test?

Thank you!

Comment: What is correlation of the genes..? What exactly do you measure?

Comment: I have 6 samples (3 controls and 3 test) and I am measuring how much a specific gene has been expressed. I want to do a correlation matrix to see if there are genes that are always expressed together or the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question, because how to define relationship between two genes quite be complicated. To my understanding, bioinformoicans tend to use something like hierarchical clustering, heat-map for comparing genes.

The simplest approach is just take the whole gene expression matrix and apply it to R's `cor` function. According to:

> https://support.bioconductor.org/p/30566/

and

> https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/qpgraph/versions/2.6.1/topics/qpPCC

you may want to use the `qpPCC` function. Please note:

- All it does is to feed all your samples into the algorithm. The function ignores your sample labels.
- You get a measure of linear correlation between two pairs of genes. But the function doesn't actually know what you mean by "expressing". It doesn't know what pattern you're talking about, all it does is just compare linear correlation between the two genes.